Icons not found when launching a QML app, program aborts
I am trying to add icons to my QML QtQuick app, the build process is fine, but when I launch the executable I get this error message:
> ./dataio
QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/qt/qml/DataIO/Main.qml:40:5: Cannot assign to non-existent property "icon"

The Main.qml line 40 is:
icon: "qrc:/qt/qml/DataIO/images/DataIO.png"

The DataIO.png file is located here:
~/source/ui_qml/DataIO/images/DataIO.png
~/DataIO_build/Desktop-Debug/DataIO/images/DataIO.png

I tried to specify the icon path in different ways, all with the same error:
icon: "./images/DataIO.png"
icon: "DataIO/images/DataIO.png"
icon: "DataIO.png"
icon: "qrc:/images/DataIO.png"
icon: "qrc:/DataIO/images/DataIO.png"
icon: "qrc:DataIO.png"
icon.source: "images/DataIO.png"
...

If I define a widget, specifying an icon as follows seems to be fine, I get no warnings/errors, but the icon effectively displayed is a default one, not the one specified:
Action {
    text: qsTr("&Connect...")
    icon.source: "images/DataIO.png"
    onTriggered: QmlLink.connect()
}

I have a manually written resource.qrc file in my source directory:
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>images/DataIO.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>

This is added to CMakeLists.txt in the qt_add_executable call:
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

qt_add_executable(dataio
    main.cpp DataIO.hpp DataIO.cpp
    resource.qrc
)

qt_add_qml_module(dataio
    URI DataIO
    VERSION 0.1
    QML_FILES
        Main.qml
    RESOURCES
        images/DataIO.png
)

In the build directory three qrc files are generated, one of which is a modified version of the manually written one:
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="/qt/qml/DataIO/">
    <file alias="Main.qml">/home/pietrom/DataIO/Main.qml</file>
    <file alias="images/DataIO.png">/home/pietrom/DataIO/images/DataIO.png</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>

Thank you for your help.

Platform:

Ubuntu 24.10
Qt 6.6


The qrc file is not intended to be added to the executable: it's normally compiled either as an rcc file (and loaded at runtime), or as an automatically generated cpp file if the project is properly configured, which will be included in the built executable. Check the related documentation. Also, based on the qrc you provided, the correct path should be qrc:/DataIO.png.

Try qrc:/qt/qml/DataIO/images/DataIO.png. By using qt_add_qml_module, CMake will generate a .qrc file for your module. By navigating to ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/.qt/rcc, you will see the generated files. If you open the .qrc file, you should notice that it has /qt/qml/DataIO as the prefix and images/DataIO.png as the alias file name.

@smr: I get no ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/.qt/rcc directory, but a .qt and a .rcc at the same level. This contains what you mentioned. The qrc is set with your path. However, I am still getting the same error.

@musicamante - I tried with qrc:/DataIO.png, but I get the same error. Shall I delete my resource.qrc file, and let the build system generate its own?

What I described is for Qt 6.8, and it would be helpful if you could also share your Qt version. However, if you found the generated qrc file, you should be able to determine the file path by appending the alias name (or the original name if no alias exists) to the prefix path. You can also use NO_RESOURCE_TARGET_PATH if you want your resources to be accessed directly from the root path (e.g., qrc:/images/DataIO.png). Also, make sure you are using icon.source, and first try loading the image inside an Image.

@smr - I added the version number to my question: Qt 6.6

In this case, icon.source: "qrc:/qt/qml/DataIO/images/DataIO.png" should work. Remember, your error is not about not finding the image; it is "non-existent property icon.", And as I stated in my last comment, you should first try using an Image component to ensure the issue is with the qrc. Also, make sure to assign the URL to icon.source directly, rather than assigning it to icon. However, as I tested on my PC, the code works fine.

@smr - Do you mean: Image appIcon: "qrc:/qt/qml/DataIO/images/DataIO.png"     icon.source: appIcon? With this I get this error: "Unexpected token `identifier'"

Just try using Action { icon.source: 'qrc:/qt/qml/DataIO/images/DataIO.png' } and see if it works.

@smr: I get no error message (neither during build nor during run), but I get no icons either. It is the same approach I used for the "Connect..." menu entry in my question. However, I noticed that with a complete path, e.g. "qrc:/qt/qml/DataIO/images/new.svg", and with a non-existent path, I get a blank space. With "qrc:images/new.svg" and "images/new.svg" I get a default icon (not the one specified in the path).
